# Column Generation/ Cutting Stock

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, pulp

Edit for clarity:

Column Generation/Cutting Stock Problem

***Must solve the master problem for the initial solution, get the dual prices, and use the dual prices to generate new patterns (sub problems) in order to re-solve the master problem with a new/additional column (pattern) for a potentially more optimal result.***

```
Raw boards are 100 units long
Current demands are:
9,700 final boards of length 45
61,000 final boards of length 36
39,500 final boards of length 31
21,100 final boards of length 14

Initial Solution (4 patterns):
Objective: minimize x1 + x2 + x3 + x4

ST:
2x1 >= 97 (lengths of 45)
x2+2x3+x4 >= 610 (lengths of 36)
x2+2x4 >= 395 (lengths of 31)
x2 >= 211(lengths of 14)
x1,x2,x3,x4 > = 0
```

The solution to this problem has an objective function value of 505, or when
the right-hand sides are multiplied by 100, we get a cost of $50,500.
This solution provides dual prices of: (.5,.5,.25,.25) for the four constraints.

However I am not well versed in PuLP and cannot properly input my specific constraints into a well crafted example I found on gitHub.

I recognize it is probably a simple task for those well versed in pulp but hoping someone can shed some light for the less knowledgable (me) on how to feed my specific requirements in.

I tried to define the below with my specific requirements and feed them into the following code also linked. (https://gist.github.com/Bart6114/8414730)

```
import random  ## to generate the items
from pulp import *  ## import pulp-or functions

maxValue = 100  # set the maximum value for the items
itemLengths = [45, 36, 31, 14]  # set the lengths of the items
itemDemands = [9700, 61000, 39500, 21100]  # set the demands for the items
initialPatterns = []  # set the initial patterns to an empty list
problemname = "column_generation"  # set the problem name


class MasterProblem:
    def __init__(self, maxValue, itemLengths, itemDemands, initialPatterns, problemname):

        self.maxValue = maxValue
        self.itemLengths = itemLengths
        self.itemDemands = itemDemands
        self.initialPatterns = initialPatterns

        self.prob = LpProblem(problemname, LpMinimize)  # set up the problem

        self.obj = LpConstraintVar("obj")  # generate a constraint variable that will be used as the objective
        self.prob.setObjective(self.obj)

        self.PatternVars = []
        self.constraintList = []  # list to save constraint variables in
        for i, x in enumerate(
                itemDemands):  # create variables & set the constraints, in other words: set the minimum amount of items to be produced
            var = LpConstraintVar("C" + str(i), LpConstraintGE, x)  # create constraintvar and set to >= demand for item
            self.constraintList.append(var)
            self.prob += var

        for i, x in enumerate(self.initialPatterns):  # save initial patterns and set column constraints
            temp = []
            for j, y in enumerate(x):
                if y > 0:
                    temp.append(j)

            var = LpVariable("Pat" + str(i), 0, None, LpContinuous, lpSum(self.obj + [self.constraintList[v] for v in
                                                                                      temp]))  # create decision variable: will determine how often pattern x should be produced
            self.PatternVars.append(var)

    def solve(self):
        self.prob.writeLP('prob.lp')
        self.prob.solve()  # start solve

        return [self.prob.constraints[i].pi for i in self.prob.constraints]

    def addPattern(self, pattern):  # add new pattern to existing model

        self.initialPatterns.append(pattern)
        temp = []

        for j, y in enumerate(pattern):
            if y > 0:
                temp.append(j)

        var = LpVariable("Pat" + str(len(self.initialPatterns)), 0, None, LpContinuous,
                         lpSum(self.obj + [pattern[v] * self.constraintList[v] for v in temp]))
        self.PatternVars.append(var)

    def startSlave(self, duals):  # create/run new slave and return new pattern (if available)

        newSlaveProb = SlaveProblem(duals, self.itemLengths, self.maxValue)

        pattern = newSlaveProb.returnPattern()
        return pattern

    def setRelaxed(self, relaxed):  # if no new patterns are available, solve model as IP problem
        if relaxed == False:
            for var in self.prob.variables():
                var.cat = LpInteger

    def getObjective(self):
        return value(self.prob.objective)

    def getUsedPatterns(self):
        usedPatternList = []
        for i, x in enumerate(self.PatternVars):
            if value(x) > 0:
                usedPatternList.append((value(x), self.initialPatterns[i]))
        return usedPatternList


class SlaveProblem:
    def __init__(self, duals, itemLengths, maxValue):
        self.slaveprob = LpProblem("Slave solver", LpMinimize)
        self.varList = [LpVariable('S' + str(i), 0, None, LpInteger) for i, x in enumerate(duals)]
        self.slaveprob += -lpSum(
            [duals[i] * x for i, x in enumerate(self.varList)])  # use duals to set objective coefficients
        self.slaveprob += lpSum([itemLengths[i] * x for i, x in enumerate(self.varList)]) <= maxValue

        self.slaveprob.writeLP('slaveprob.lp')
        self.slaveprob.solve()
        self.slaveprob.roundSolution()  # to avoid rounding problems

    def returnPattern(self):
        pattern = False
        if value(self.slaveprob.objective) < -1.00001:
            pattern = []
            for v in self.varList:
                pattern.append(value(v))
        return pattern


random.seed(2012)

nrItems = 12
lengthSheets = 20

itemLengths = []
itemDemands = []

while len(itemLengths) != nrItems:
    length = random.randint(5, lengthSheets - 2)
    demand = random.randint(5, 100)
    if length not in itemLengths:
        itemLengths.append(length)
        itemDemands.append(demand)

print
"Item lengts  : %s" % itemLengths
print
"Item demands : %s\n\n" % itemDemands

patterns = []
print
"Generating start patterns:"
## generate simple start patterns
for x in range(nrItems):
    temp = [0.0 for y in range(x)]
    temp.append(1.0)
    temp += [0.0 for y in range(nrItems - x - 1)]
    patterns.append(temp)
    print
    temp

print
"\n\nTrying to solve problem"
CGprob = MasterProblem(lengthSheets, itemLengths, itemDemands, patterns, '1D cutting stock')

relaxed = True
while relaxed == True:  # once no more new columns can be generated set relaxed to False
    duals = CGprob.solve()

    newPattern = CGprob.startSlave(duals)

    print
    'New pattern: %s' % newPattern

    if newPattern:
        CGprob.addPattern(newPattern)
    else:
        CGprob.setRelaxed(False)
        CGprob.solve()
        relaxed = False

print
"\n\nSolution: %s sheets required" % CGprob.getObjective()

t = CGprob.getUsedPatterns()
for i, x in enumerate(t):
    print
    "Pattern %s: selected %s times  %s" % (i, x[0], x[1])
```

Comment: You need to edit your question and add more detail about what your constraints and objective are, since currently you just describe a list of numbers and no information on how they relate to each other.

Comment: Are you using Python 2? Your print syntax is invalid

Comment: what do `x1, x2, x3, x4` represent?  I would think they would be the count of boards of the 4 lengths, but then the constraint you have doesn't make sense...?

Comment: Decision variables:
• x1: number of raw boards in hundreds cut with pattern 1
• x2: number of raw boards in hundreds cut with pattern 2
• x3: number of raw boards in hundreds cut with pattern 3
• x4: number of raw boards in hundreds cut with pattern 4

Comment: Ummmm...  that implies you have already selected 4 and only 4 patterns because you are stating how many of each board length each pattern produces?

Comment: My original question is that given this information :

• Raw boards are 100 units long
• Current demands are:
• 9,700 finals of length 45
• 61,000 finals of length 36
• 39,500 finals of length 31
• 21,100 finals of length 14

I do not understand how to properly code a column generation problem. I have solutions given to me (for instance the above 4 patterns) with an objective function equal to 505. However I am trying to figure out how to specifically solve in PuLP, to get not only this solution but also to use the dual prices to generate columns/new patterns (up to 6).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will help...  I'm not sure if you are looking to manually build your own solving routine by making columns in a sub-problem, but in this case, with a little creativity, you can deduce that there are only 38 usable patterns.

At most, with your dimensions, a pattern can produce 7 boards ( 7 boards @ 14' < 100' ).  So building a superset of all the 7-selection items and filtering it down leaves you 38.

That becomes a real simple ILP:

```
import pulp
from itertools import product
from collections import Counter

requirements = {    45: 9700,
                    36: 61000,
                    31: 39500,
                    14: 21100}

bds = list(requirements.keys())
stock_length = 100

# let's just enumerate the columns (patterns)
bds.append(0)  # appending a zero allows "non-selection"
patterns = list(filter(lambda x: sum(x) <= stock_length, product(bds, repeat=7)))
# clean up the stray zeros in the patterns...
#   sort the elements of the pattern so that we can find duplicates...
#     make the pattern a tuple so it can be a dict key...
#       turn patterns into a set to remove duplicates...
patterns = set(tuple(sorted(filter(lambda x: x>0, pattern))) for pattern in patterns)
print(f'There are only {len(patterns)} usable patterns')

# make a parameter for the count of boards produced of each type by pattern
production = {pattern: Counter(pattern) for pattern in patterns}


# make the pulp problem
prob = pulp.LpProblem('pattern_chopper', pulp.LpMinimize)

# make the variable
x = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('pattern', patterns, cat=pulp.LpInteger, lowBound=0)

# objective:  minimize the raw stock (sum of pattern count) used
prob += pulp.lpSum(x)

# constraint produce at least the reqt in boards
for board in requirements.keys():
    prob += sum(x[p] * production[p][board] for p in patterns) >= requirements[board]

soln = prob.solve()

print(soln)

for pattern in patterns:
    if x[pattern].varValue:
        print(f'make {x[pattern].varValue} of {pattern}')
```

##### Output:

```
Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                45225.00000000
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               0
Time (CPU seconds):             0.00
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.00

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.00   (Wallclock seconds):       0.00

make 19750.0 of (31, 31, 36)
make 4850.0 of (45, 45)
make 10550.0 of (14, 14, 36, 36)
make 10075.0 of (36, 36)
[Finished in 129ms]
```

Comment: (My question is based off a practice problem for Integer Programming and we are focusing on column generation, and generating patterns via subproblems to iterate through the master problem) - however your method is very succinct and much easier/user friendly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult problem, or at least I had a difficult time producing an efficient solution. I demonstrate a solution that does not use your `CG`. Effectively we need a product of length counts * sheet counts per pattern, but of course that's non-linear so to linearize I demonstrate a method that uses binary assignment variables multiple times per potential length.

I ran it for three patterns and it takes about a minute; 12 patterns will be slower.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pulp


def make_selects(row: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    repeat, length = row.name

    # Within this pattern and length, is this length repeat used?
    selects = [pulp.LpVariable(name=f'select_p{pat:02d}_l{length}_r{repeat}', cat=pulp.LpBinary)
              for pat in pattern_idx]

    return pd.Series(data=selects, index=pattern_idx)


def make_select_sheets(select: pulp.LpVariable) -> pulp.LpVariable:
    suffix = select.name.removeprefix('select')

    # Within this pattern, length and length repeat, how many sheets are assigned: 0, or the same number
    # of sheets as the pattern overall?
    select_sheets = pulp.LpVariable(name='selectsheet' + suffix, cat=pulp.LpInteger, lowBound=0)

    # If select==0, select_sheets=0
    buffer = 10*demands.max()
    prob.addConstraint(name='zerosheets' + suffix, constraint=select_sheets <= buffer*select)
    return select_sheets


def constrain_pats(selects_col: pd.Series) -> None:
    pat = selects_col.name
    lengths = selects_col.index.get_level_values('length')

    # Every pattern's used length must be at most the raw length
    prob.addConstraint(name=f'raw_p{pat:02d}', constraint=pulp.lpDot(lengths, selects_col) <= raw_length)

    # For compactness: within a pattern and length, put all of the length-repeat ones together
    for length, group in selects_col.groupby(level='length'):
        for ((first_repeat, _), first), ((second_repeat, _), second) in zip(group[:-1].items(), group[1:].items()):
            prob.addConstraint(name=f'compact_p{pat:02d}_l{length}_r{first_repeat}{second_repeat}', constraint=first <= second)

    # If the given length is selected, force its select-sheets count to be equal to the pattern sheet count
    for (repeat, length), select in selects_col.items():
        single_sheets = select_sheets.loc[(repeat, length), pat]
        overall_sheets = pat_sheets.loc[pat]
        diff = single_sheets - overall_sheets
        tolerance = (1 - select)*10*demands.max()
        suffix = f'_p{pat:02d}_l{length}_r{repeat}'

        # If select==1, select_sheets=overall_sheets
        # overall_sheets - select_sheets <= (1-select)*buffer
        # select_sheets - overall_sheets <= (1-select)*buffer
        prob.addConstraint(name='sheetmatchpos' + suffix, constraint=diff <= tolerance)
        prob.addConstraint(name='sheetmatchneg' + suffix, constraint=-diff <= tolerance)


def constrain_lengths(group: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
    # For a group of one length over multiple patterns and length-repeats, the sum sheet count must satisfy demand
    length = group.name
    total = pulp.lpSum(group.melt().value)
    demand = demands[length]
    prob.addConstraint(name=f'demand_l{length}', constraint=total >= demand)


prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='sheet_cutting', sense=pulp.LpMinimize)
raw_length = 100
lengths = pd.Series(name='length', data=(45, 36, 31, 14))

# Linearize the lengths in a pattern by splitting them into multiple "length repeats" with one binary selector each,
# up to the number of lengths that could fit in the raw length
repeats = np.arange(1, 1+raw_length//lengths.min())
length_contributions = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.outer(repeats, lengths),
    columns=lengths,
    index=pd.Index(name='repeat', data=repeats),
).stack()
length_contributions = pd.DataFrame(
    length_contributions[length_contributions <= 100].sort_index(level=['length', 'repeat']),
    columns=['contribution'])

n_patterns = 3  # 12
pattern_idx = pd.Series(name='pattern', data=np.arange(n_patterns))

# Decision variables - sheets consumed per pattern
pat_sheets = pd.Series(
    name='pat_sheets', index=pattern_idx,
    data=[pulp.LpVariable(name=f'pat_sheets_p{pat:02d}', cat=pulp.LpInteger, lowBound=0)
          for pat in pattern_idx])
demands = pd.Series(name='demand', data=(9_700, 61_000, 39_500, 21_100), index=lengths)

# Decision variables - binary, for each pattern, should this length and length-repeat be included?
selects: pd.DataFrame = length_contributions.apply(make_selects, axis=1)

# Decision variables - integer, for each pattern, either 0 or the number of sheets consumed by this length and length-repeat
select_sheets = selects.applymap(make_select_sheets)

selects.apply(constrain_pats, axis=0)

select_sheets.groupby(level='length').apply(constrain_lengths)

prob.objective = pulp.lpSum(pat_sheets)
print(prob)
prob.solve()
assert prob.status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

print('Sheets consumed per pattern:')
pat_sheets = pat_sheets.apply(pulp.LpVariable.value).astype(int)
print(pat_sheets)
print()

print('Pattern usage of each length option:')
selects = selects.applymap(pulp.LpVariable.value).astype(int)
print(selects)
print()

print('Portion of raw used in each pattern:')
print(selects.index.get_level_values('length') @ selects)
print()

print('Production per length:')
select_sheets = select_sheets.applymap(pulp.LpVariable.value)
print(select_sheets.groupby(level='length').sum().sum(axis=1))
print()
```

```
sheet_cutting:
MINIMIZE
1*pat_sheets_p00 + 1*pat_sheets_p01 + 1*pat_sheets_p02 + 0
SUBJECT TO
zerosheets_p00_l14_r1: - 610000 select_p00_l14_r1 + selectsheet_p00_l14_r1
 <= 0
...
zerosheets_p02_l45_r2: - 610000 select_p02_l45_r2 + selectsheet_p02_l45_r2
 <= 0

raw_p00: 14 select_p00_l14_r1 + 14 select_p00_l14_r2 + 14 select_p00_l14_r3
 + 14 select_p00_l14_r4 + 14 select_p00_l14_r5 + 14 select_p00_l14_r6
 + 14 select_p00_l14_r7 + 31 select_p00_l31_r1 + 31 select_p00_l31_r2
 + 31 select_p00_l31_r3 + 36 select_p00_l36_r1 + 36 select_p00_l36_r2
 + 45 select_p00_l45_r1 + 45 select_p00_l45_r2 <= 100

compact_p00_l14_r12: select_p00_l14_r1 - select_p00_l14_r2 <= 0

compact_p00_l14_r23: select_p00_l14_r2 - select_p00_l14_r3 <= 0

compact_p00_l14_r34: select_p00_l14_r3 - select_p00_l14_r4 <= 0

compact_p00_l14_r45: select_p00_l14_r4 - select_p00_l14_r5 <= 0

compact_p00_l14_r56: select_p00_l14_r5 - select_p00_l14_r6 <= 0

compact_p00_l14_r67: select_p00_l14_r6 - select_p00_l14_r7 <= 0

compact_p00_l31_r12: select_p00_l31_r1 - select_p00_l31_r2 <= 0

compact_p00_l31_r23: select_p00_l31_r2 - select_p00_l31_r3 <= 0

compact_p00_l36_r12: select_p00_l36_r1 - select_p00_l36_r2 <= 0

compact_p00_l45_r12: select_p00_l45_r1 - select_p00_l45_r2 <= 0

sheetmatchpos_p00_l14_r1: - pat_sheets_p00 + 610000 select_p00_l14_r1
 + selectsheet_p00_l14_r1 <= 610000

sheetmatchneg_p00_l14_r1: pat_sheets_p00 + 610000 select_p00_l14_r1
 - selectsheet_p00_l14_r1 <= 610000

...

demand_l14: selectsheet_p00_l14_r1 + selectsheet_p00_l14_r2
 + selectsheet_p00_l14_r3 + selectsheet_p00_l14_r4 + selectsheet_p00_l14_r5
 + selectsheet_p00_l14_r6 + selectsheet_p00_l14_r7 + selectsheet_p01_l14_r1
 + selectsheet_p01_l14_r2 + selectsheet_p01_l14_r3 + selectsheet_p01_l14_r4
 + selectsheet_p01_l14_r5 + selectsheet_p01_l14_r6 + selectsheet_p01_l14_r7
 + selectsheet_p02_l14_r1 + selectsheet_p02_l14_r2 + selectsheet_p02_l14_r3
 + selectsheet_p02_l14_r4 + selectsheet_p02_l14_r5 + selectsheet_p02_l14_r6
 + selectsheet_p02_l14_r7 >= 21100

demand_l31: selectsheet_p00_l31_r1 + selectsheet_p00_l31_r2
 + selectsheet_p00_l31_r3 + selectsheet_p01_l31_r1 + selectsheet_p01_l31_r2
 + selectsheet_p01_l31_r3 + selectsheet_p02_l31_r1 + selectsheet_p02_l31_r2
 + selectsheet_p02_l31_r3 >= 39500

demand_l36: selectsheet_p00_l36_r1 + selectsheet_p00_l36_r2
 + selectsheet_p01_l36_r1 + selectsheet_p01_l36_r2 + selectsheet_p02_l36_r1
 + selectsheet_p02_l36_r2 >= 61000

demand_l45: selectsheet_p00_l45_r1 + selectsheet_p00_l45_r2
 + selectsheet_p01_l45_r1 + selectsheet_p01_l45_r2 + selectsheet_p02_l45_r1
 + selectsheet_p02_l45_r2 >= 9700

VARIABLES
0 <= pat_sheets_p00 Integer
0 <= pat_sheets_p01 Integer
0 <= pat_sheets_p02 Integer
0 <= select_p00_l14_r1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p00_l14_r2 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p00_l14_r3 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p00_l14_r4 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p00_l14_r5 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p00_l14_r6 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p00_l14_r7 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p00_l31_r1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p00_l31_r2 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p00_l31_r3 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p00_l36_r1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p00_l36_r2 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p00_l45_r1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p00_l45_r2 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p01_l14_r1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p01_l14_r2 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p01_l14_r3 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p01_l14_r4 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p01_l14_r5 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p01_l14_r6 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p01_l14_r7 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p01_l31_r1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p01_l31_r2 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p01_l31_r3 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p01_l36_r1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p01_l36_r2 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p01_l45_r1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p01_l45_r2 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p02_l14_r1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p02_l14_r2 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p02_l14_r3 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p02_l14_r4 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p02_l14_r5 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p02_l14_r6 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p02_l14_r7 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p02_l31_r1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p02_l31_r2 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p02_l31_r3 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p02_l36_r1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p02_l36_r2 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p02_l45_r1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= select_p02_l45_r2 <= 1 Integer
0 <= selectsheet_p00_l14_r1 Integer
0 <= selectsheet_p00_l14_r2 Integer
0 <= selectsheet_p00_l14_r3 Integer
0 <= selectsheet_p00_l14_r4 Integer
...
0 <= selectsheet_p02_l45_r2 Integer

Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
Version: 2.10.3 
Build Date: Dec 15 2019 

command line - .venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pulp/solverdir/cbc/linux/64/cbc /tmp/9e2a4dc42778439a8384255fe1bea41c-pulp.mps timeMode elapsed branch printingOptions all solution /tmp/9e2a4dc42778439a8384255fe1bea41c-pulp.sol (default strategy 1)
At line 2 NAME          MODEL
At line 3 ROWS
At line 168 COLUMNS
At line 826 RHS
At line 990 BOUNDS
At line 1078 ENDATA
Problem MODEL has 163 rows, 87 columns and 480 elements
Coin0008I MODEL read with 0 errors
Option for timeMode changed from cpu to elapsed
Continuous objective value is 0 - 0.00 seconds
Cgl0003I 0 fixed, 6 tightened bounds, 42 strengthened rows, 0 substitutions
Cgl0003I 0 fixed, 0 tightened bounds, 17 strengthened rows, 0 substitutions
Cgl0003I 0 fixed, 0 tightened bounds, 6 strengthened rows, 0 substitutions
Cgl0004I processed model has 163 rows, 87 columns (87 integer (42 of which binary)) and 539 elements
Cutoff increment increased from 1e-05 to 0.9999
Cbc0045I 3 integer variables out of 87 objects (87 integer) have cost of 1 - high priority
Cbc0045I branch on satisfied N create fake objective N random cost N
Cbc0038I Initial state - 7 integers unsatisfied sum - 0.429836
Cbc0038I Pass   1: suminf.    1.54858 (11) obj. 7033.33 iterations 70
Cbc0038I Pass   2: suminf.    0.48889 (1) obj. 80750 iterations 33
Cbc0038I Pass   3: suminf.    0.01590 (1) obj. 80750 iterations 1
Cbc0038I Pass   4: suminf.    4.29368 (13) obj. 34016.7 iterations 20
Cbc0038I Pass   5: suminf.    4.29368 (13) obj. 34016.7 iterations 5
Cbc0038I Pass   6: suminf.    3.87701 (14) obj. 34016.7 iterations 19
Cbc0038I Pass   7: suminf.    1.34923 (5) obj. 74166.7 iterations 13
Cbc0038I Pass   8: suminf.    1.82222 (5) obj. 74166.7 iterations 1
Cbc0038I Pass   9: suminf.    0.58387 (2) obj. 9700 iterations 25
Cbc0038I Pass  10: suminf.    0.58387 (2) obj. 9700 iterations 3
Cbc0038I Pass  11: suminf.    1.60000 (6) obj. 360978 iterations 7
Cbc0038I Pass  12: suminf.    0.01590 (1) obj. 649500 iterations 2
Cbc0038I Pass  13: suminf.    0.04444 (1) obj. 629750 iterations 22
Cbc0038I Pass  14: suminf.    0.01590 (1) obj. 629750 iterations 9
Cbc0038I Pass  15: suminf.    0.71111 (2) obj. 629750 iterations 5
Cbc0038I Pass  16: suminf.    7.44941 (32) obj. 688710 iterations 44
Cbc0038I Pass  17: suminf.    0.12031 (3) obj. 610000 iterations 22
Cbc0038I Pass  18: suminf.    3.03250 (16) obj. 649355 iterations 5
Cbc0038I Pass  19: suminf.    3.64540 (14) obj. 688710 iterations 1
Cbc0038I Pass  20: suminf.    4.00952 (16) obj. 736643 iterations 48
Cbc0038I Pass  21: suminf.    0.00000 (0) obj. 654350 iterations 19
Cbc0038I Solution found of 654350
Cbc0038I Cleaned solution of 654350
Cbc0038I Before mini branch and bound, 20 integers at bound fixed and 0 continuous
Cbc0038I Full problem 163 rows 87 columns, reduced to 126 rows 67 columns - 2 fixed gives 122, 65 - still too large
Cbc0038I Full problem 163 rows 87 columns, reduced to 122 rows 65 columns - too large
Cbc0038I Mini branch and bound did not improve solution (0.02 seconds)
Cbc0038I Round again with cutoff of 588914
Cbc0038I Pass  22: suminf.    1.54858 (11) obj. 7033.33 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  23: suminf.    0.48889 (1) obj. 80750 iterations 48
Cbc0038I Pass  24: suminf.    0.01590 (1) obj. 80750 iterations 4
Cbc0038I Pass  25: suminf.    0.01590 (1) obj. 80750 iterations 12
Cbc0038I Pass  26: suminf.    0.01590 (1) obj. 80750 iterations 6
Cbc0038I Pass  27: suminf.    0.68257 (3) obj. 30500 iterations 35
Cbc0038I Pass  28: suminf.    0.01590 (1) obj. 80750 iterations 17
Cbc0038I Pass  29: suminf.    0.17778 (1) obj. 80750 iterations 4
Cbc0038I Pass  30: suminf.    0.00000 (0) obj. 85600 iterations 12
Cbc0038I Solution found of 85600
Cbc0038I Cleaned solution of 85600
Cbc0038I Before mini branch and bound, 53 integers at bound fixed and 0 continuous
Cbc0038I Full problem 163 rows 87 columns, reduced to 60 rows 34 columns
Cbc0038I Mini branch and bound improved solution from 85600 to 61000 (0.03 seconds)
Cbc0038I Round again with cutoff of 48799.2
Cbc0038I Pass  31: suminf.    1.54858 (11) obj. 7033.33 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  32: suminf.    1.32191 (6) obj. 48799.2 iterations 53
Cbc0038I Pass  33: suminf.    0.91622 (6) obj. 48799.2 iterations 5
Cbc0038I Pass  34: suminf.    1.80203 (11) obj. 48799.2 iterations 14
Cbc0038I Pass  35: suminf.    1.79408 (9) obj. 48799.2 iterations 8
Cbc0038I Pass  36: suminf.    1.10040 (6) obj. 48799.2 iterations 16
Cbc0038I Pass  37: suminf.    1.06073 (6) obj. 48799.2 iterations 1
Cbc0038I Pass  38: suminf.    1.07663 (9) obj. 48799.2 iterations 20
Cbc0038I Pass  39: suminf.    1.06868 (7) obj. 48799.2 iterations 8
Cbc0038I Pass  40: suminf.    1.47810 (9) obj. 48799.2 iterations 6
Cbc0038I Pass  41: suminf.    4.76550 (14) obj. 48799.2 iterations 11
Cbc0038I Pass  42: suminf.    0.85119 (6) obj. 48799.2 iterations 24
Cbc0038I Pass  43: suminf.    1.16145 (6) obj. 48799.2 iterations 31
Cbc0038I Pass  44: suminf.    1.16145 (6) obj. 48799.2 iterations 2
Cbc0038I Pass  45: suminf.    0.51606 (4) obj. 48799.2 iterations 7
Cbc0038I Pass  46: suminf.    1.27246 (7) obj. 48799.2 iterations 19
Cbc0038I Pass  47: suminf.    1.06868 (7) obj. 48799.2 iterations 1
Cbc0038I Pass  48: suminf.    1.47810 (9) obj. 48799.2 iterations 5
Cbc0038I Pass  49: suminf.    5.09883 (15) obj. 48799.2 iterations 8
Cbc0038I Pass  50: suminf.    0.85119 (6) obj. 48799.2 iterations 21
Cbc0038I Pass  51: suminf.    1.15746 (6) obj. 48799.2 iterations 12
Cbc0038I Pass  52: suminf.    0.84487 (6) obj. 48799.2 iterations 4
Cbc0038I Pass  53: suminf.    1.15746 (6) obj. 48799.2 iterations 1
Cbc0038I Pass  54: suminf.    1.32146 (4) obj. 30300 iterations 25
Cbc0038I Pass  55: suminf.    0.96035 (3) obj. 41050 iterations 13
Cbc0038I Pass  56: suminf.    1.30929 (7) obj. 48799.2 iterations 13
Cbc0038I Pass  57: suminf.    1.03630 (7) obj. 48799.2 iterations 2
Cbc0038I Pass  58: suminf.    1.35754 (7) obj. 48799.2 iterations 1
Cbc0038I Pass  59: suminf.    5.62826 (18) obj. 48799.2 iterations 42
Cbc0038I Pass  60: suminf.    2.66910 (14) obj. 48799.2 iterations 18
Cbc0038I No solution found this major pass
Cbc0038I Before mini branch and bound, 26 integers at bound fixed and 0 continuous
Cbc0038I Full problem 163 rows 87 columns, reduced to 112 rows 61 columns
Cbc0038I Mini branch and bound improved solution from 61000 to 55100 (0.10 seconds)
Cbc0038I Round again with cutoff of 34159.4
Cbc0038I Pass  60: suminf.    1.54858 (11) obj. 7033.33 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  61: suminf.    2.28661 (6) obj. 34159.4 iterations 53
Cbc0038I Pass  62: suminf.    1.87613 (6) obj. 34159.4 iterations 5
Cbc0038I Pass  63: suminf.    3.32673 (15) obj. 34159.4 iterations 33
Cbc0038I Pass  64: suminf.    3.16367 (9) obj. 34159.4 iterations 3
Cbc0038I Pass  65: suminf.    1.46351 (6) obj. 34159.4 iterations 14
Cbc0038I Pass  66: suminf.    1.53544 (5) obj. 34159.4 iterations 33
Cbc0038I Pass  67: suminf.    1.43607 (5) obj. 34159.4 iterations 2
Cbc0038I Pass  68: suminf.    3.19175 (22) obj. 34159.4 iterations 42
Cbc0038I Pass  69: suminf.    1.88627 (6) obj. 34159.4 iterations 8
Cbc0038I Pass  70: suminf.    1.54588 (6) obj. 34159.4 iterations 35
Cbc0038I Pass  71: suminf.    1.45417 (5) obj. 34159.4 iterations 24
Cbc0038I Pass  72: suminf.    1.41245 (5) obj. 34159.4 iterations 21
Cbc0038I Pass  73: suminf.    1.86022 (5) obj. 34159.4 iterations 5
Cbc0038I Pass  74: suminf.    1.53544 (5) obj. 34159.4 iterations 3
Cbc0038I Pass  75: suminf.    1.90297 (9) obj. 34159.4 iterations 22
Cbc0038I Pass  76: suminf.    1.81033 (9) obj. 34159.4 iterations 23
Cbc0038I Pass  77: suminf.    1.45910 (5) obj. 34159.4 iterations 25
Cbc0038I Pass  78: suminf.    1.38883 (5) obj. 34159.4 iterations 4
Cbc0038I Pass  79: suminf.    2.91811 (8) obj. 34159.4 iterations 24
Cbc0038I Pass  80: suminf.    2.72466 (7) obj. 34159.4 iterations 14
Cbc0038I Pass  81: suminf.    2.91811 (7) obj. 34159.4 iterations 2
Cbc0038I Pass  82: suminf.    3.23798 (10) obj. 34159.4 iterations 12
Cbc0038I Pass  83: suminf.    2.75704 (9) obj. 34159.4 iterations 12
Cbc0038I Pass  84: suminf.    3.80528 (11) obj. 34159.4 iterations 14
Cbc0038I Pass  85: suminf.    2.86937 (8) obj. 34159.4 iterations 1
Cbc0038I Pass  86: suminf.    2.75704 (8) obj. 34159.4 iterations 2
Cbc0038I Pass  87: suminf.    1.78847 (12) obj. 34159.4 iterations 38
Cbc0038I Pass  88: suminf.    1.40712 (6) obj. 34159.4 iterations 9
Cbc0038I Pass  89: suminf.    2.74849 (14) obj. 34159.4 iterations 21
Cbc0038I No solution found this major pass
Cbc0038I Before mini branch and bound, 22 integers at bound fixed and 0 continuous
Cbc0038I Full problem 163 rows 87 columns, reduced to 120 rows 65 columns - 1 fixed gives 118, 64 - ok now
Cbc0038I Full problem 163 rows 87 columns, reduced to 118 rows 64 columns
Cbc0038I Mini branch and bound improved solution from 55100 to 45225 (0.14 seconds)
Cbc0038I Round again with cutoff of 23911.6
Cbc0038I Pass  89: suminf.    1.54858 (11) obj. 7033.33 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  90: suminf.    2.69567 (10) obj. 23911.6 iterations 56
Cbc0038I Pass  91: suminf.    2.31044 (10) obj. 23911.6 iterations 6
Cbc0038I Pass  92: suminf.    1.76258 (10) obj. 23911.6 iterations 52
Cbc0038I Pass  93: suminf.    1.91812 (8) obj. 23911.6 iterations 12
Cbc0038I Pass  94: suminf.    2.20231 (8) obj. 23911.6 iterations 27
Cbc0038I Pass  95: suminf.    1.31008 (5) obj. 23911.6 iterations 18
Cbc0038I Pass  96: suminf.    1.28679 (6) obj. 23911.6 iterations 3
Cbc0038I Pass  97: suminf.    1.33231 (7) obj. 23911.6 iterations 5
Cbc0038I Pass  98: suminf.    1.51158 (7) obj. 23911.6 iterations 12
Cbc0038I Pass  99: suminf.    2.15203 (10) obj. 23911.6 iterations 4
Cbc0038I Pass 100: suminf.    1.30176 (6) obj. 23911.6 iterations 7
Cbc0038I Pass 101: suminf.    1.51151 (7) obj. 23911.6 iterations 5
Cbc0038I Pass 102: suminf.    1.52175 (6) obj. 23911.6 iterations 11
Cbc0038I Pass 103: suminf.    1.28679 (6) obj. 23911.6 iterations 1
Cbc0038I Pass 104: suminf.    1.30176 (6) obj. 23911.6 iterations 7
Cbc0038I Pass 105: suminf.    1.29543 (6) obj. 23911.6 iterations 5
Cbc0038I Pass 106: suminf.    1.55230 (6) obj. 23911.6 iterations 3
Cbc0038I Pass 107: suminf.    1.31734 (6) obj. 23911.6 iterations 1
Cbc0038I Pass 108: suminf.    1.30176 (6) obj. 23911.6 iterations 4
Cbc0038I Pass 109: suminf.    1.51151 (7) obj. 23911.6 iterations 5
Cbc0038I Pass 110: suminf.    1.52175 (6) obj. 23911.6 iterations 5
Cbc0038I Pass 111: suminf.    1.28679 (6) obj. 23911.6 iterations 1
Cbc0038I Pass 112: suminf.    1.30176 (6) obj. 23911.6 iterations 7
Cbc0038I Pass 113: suminf.    1.29543 (6) obj. 23911.6 iterations 5
Cbc0038I Pass 114: suminf.    1.55230 (6) obj. 23911.6 iterations 3
Cbc0038I Pass 115: suminf.    1.31734 (6) obj. 23911.6 iterations 1
Cbc0038I Pass 116: suminf.    1.30176 (6) obj. 23911.6 iterations 4
Cbc0038I Pass 117: suminf.    1.51151 (7) obj. 23911.6 iterations 5
Cbc0038I Pass 118: suminf.    1.52175 (6) obj. 23911.6 iterations 5
Cbc0038I No solution found this major pass
Cbc0038I Before mini branch and bound, 50 integers at bound fixed and 0 continuous
Cbc0038I Full problem 163 rows 87 columns, reduced to 63 rows 36 columns
Cbc0038I Mini branch and bound did not improve solution (0.15 seconds)
Cbc0038I After 0.15 seconds - Feasibility pump exiting with objective of 45225 - took 0.14 seconds
Cbc0012I Integer solution of 45225 found by feasibility pump after 0 iterations and 0 nodes (0.15 seconds)
Cbc0038I Full problem 163 rows 87 columns, reduced to 45 rows 27 columns
Cbc0031I 24 added rows had average density of 5.875
Cbc0013I At root node, 24 cuts changed objective from 0 to 30500 in 38 passes
Cbc0014I Cut generator 0 (Probing) - 254 row cuts average 4.6 elements, 40 column cuts (40 active)  in 0.018 seconds - new frequency is 1
Cbc0014I Cut generator 1 (Gomory) - 230 row cuts average 18.6 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.006 seconds - new frequency is 1
Cbc0014I Cut generator 2 (Knapsack) - 18 row cuts average 6.9 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.005 seconds - new frequency is 1
Cbc0014I Cut generator 3 (Clique) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.000 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0014I Cut generator 4 (MixedIntegerRounding2) - 18 row cuts average 8.6 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.004 seconds - new frequency is 1
Cbc0014I Cut generator 5 (FlowCover) - 21 row cuts average 2.5 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.003 seconds - new frequency is 1
Cbc0014I Cut generator 6 (TwoMirCuts) - 106 row cuts average 13.8 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.003 seconds - new frequency is 1
Cbc0010I After 0 nodes, 1 on tree, 45225 best solution, best possible 30500 (0.21 seconds)
Cbc0038I Full problem 163 rows 87 columns, reduced to 87 rows 47 columns
Cbc0038I Full problem 163 rows 87 columns, reduced to 78 rows 44 columns
Cbc0038I Full problem 163 rows 87 columns, reduced to 66 rows 37 columns
Cbc0038I Full problem 163 rows 87 columns, reduced to 65 rows 37 columns
Cbc0038I Full problem 163 rows 87 columns, reduced to 67 rows 38 columns
Cbc0038I Full problem 163 rows 87 columns, reduced to 72 rows 41 columns
Cbc0038I Full problem 163 rows 87 columns, reduced to 71 rows 40 columns
Cbc0038I Full problem 163 rows 87 columns, reduced to 60 rows 35 columns
Cbc0038I Full problem 163 rows 87 columns, reduced to 56 rows 32 columns
Cbc0010I After 1000 nodes, 206 on tree, 45225 best solution, best possible 30500 (10.09 seconds)
Cbc0038I Full problem 163 rows 87 columns, reduced to 66 rows 38 columns
Cbc0010I After 2000 nodes, 132 on tree, 45225 best solution, best possible 30500 (22.86 seconds)
Cbc0010I After 3000 nodes, 70 on tree, 45225 best solution, best possible 30500 (24.75 seconds)
Cbc0038I Full problem 163 rows 87 columns, reduced to 86 rows 47 columns
Cbc0010I After 4000 nodes, 18 on tree, 45225 best solution, best possible 30500 (26.72 seconds)
Cbc0038I Full problem 163 rows 87 columns, reduced to 66 rows 38 columns
Cbc0010I After 5000 nodes, 8 on tree, 45225 best solution, best possible 30500 (28.66 seconds)
Cbc0038I Full problem 163 rows 87 columns, reduced to 84 rows 47 columns
Cbc0038I Full problem 163 rows 87 columns, reduced to 77 rows 44 columns
Cbc0010I After 6000 nodes, 11 on tree, 45225 best solution, best possible 30500 (30.45 seconds)
Cbc0038I Full problem 163 rows 87 columns, reduced to 75 rows 43 columns
Cbc0010I After 7000 nodes, 6 on tree, 45225 best solution, best possible 30500 (32.60 seconds)
Cbc0038I Full problem 163 rows 87 columns, reduced to 63 rows 36 columns
Cbc0001I Search completed - best objective 45225, took 1936041 iterations and 161352 nodes (33.76 seconds)
Cbc0032I Strong branching done 3720 times (26955 iterations), fathomed 33 nodes and fixed 25 variables
Cbc0041I Maximum depth 47, 963 variables fixed on reduced cost (complete fathoming 36 times, 153780 nodes taking 1618106 iterations)
Cuts at root node changed objective from 0 to 30500
Probing was tried 12614 times and created 265539 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (2.485 seconds)
Gomory was tried 11798 times and created 110667 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (1.811 seconds)
Knapsack was tried 11799 times and created 9365 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (1.153 seconds)
Clique was tried 38 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
MixedIntegerRounding2 was tried 11799 times and created 6237 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.841 seconds)
FlowCover was tried 11799 times and created 22421 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.822 seconds)
TwoMirCuts was tried 11798 times and created 13856 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.524 seconds)
ZeroHalf was tried 1 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
ImplicationCuts was tried 1134 times and created 1005 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.009 seconds)

Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                45225.00000000
Enumerated nodes:               161352
Total iterations:               1936041
Time (CPU seconds):             32.94
Time (Wallclock seconds):       33.76

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       32.94   (Wallclock seconds):       33.76

Sheets consumed per pattern:
pattern
0    15775
1    19750
2     9700
Name: pat_sheets, dtype: int64

Pattern usage of each length option:
pattern        0  1  2
repeat length         
1      14      0  0  0
2      14      0  0  0
3      14      0  0  0
4      14      0  0  0
5      14      0  0  0
6      14      0  0  0
7      14      1  0  1
1      31      0  0  0
2      31      0  1  0
3      31      0  1  0
1      36      1  0  0
2      36      1  1  1
1      45      0  0  0
2      45      0  0  1

Portion of raw used in each pattern:
pattern
0    86
1    98
2    95
dtype: int64

Production per length:
length
14    25475.0
31    39500.0
36    61000.0
45     9700.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you - your code is generally helpful as a sheet cutting solution. However I need to utilize column generation and find new patterns within the master problem to solve for a more optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a simple tool for solving 1D Cutting Stock problem. It is being effectively used by a paper mill in Vietnam. You can try it at: https://cutting-stock.vercel.app/